# PostgreSQL user-defined operator function: what parameter type to use for uncast character string?

Tags: sql, operator-overloading, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.3, user-defined-types

(*Cross-posted to (and [answered on](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15491.1406815380@sss.pgh.pa.us)) [pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140731053324.GA94831@scruffle.mackler.org)*)

I'm using PostgreSQL, defining my own domain and a equality operator.  I cannot cause PostgreSQL to use my operator function in a query without explicitly casting a character-string argument to the type I used in defining the operator.  My question is how to cause my custom operator to be used without the cast.

As an example: first I define a domain and a table column of that type.  For this example, the type requires its values to be three uppercase letters `A`, `B` or `C`, and the equality operator will cause queries to match regardless of case.

```
CREATE domain my_domain as char(3) check(VALUE similar to '[A-C]{3}');
CREATE TABLE my_table (val my_domain);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('ABC');
```

The type of the column is `my_domain`:

```
sandbox=> \d my_table
    Table "public.my_table"
 Column |   Type    | Modifiers 
--------+-----------+-----------
 val    | my_domain |
```

Before defining the custom equality operator, case-sensitive queries work as I expect.  The row in the table is capital letters, so the query must contain capital letters to match the row

```
sandbox=> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE val='abc';
 val 
-----
(0 rows)

sandbox=> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE val='ABC';
 val 
-----
 ABC
(1 row)
```

Next I create an equality operator to do case-insensitive matching:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_equals(this my_domain, that text) RETURNS boolean AS
'SELECT CAST (this AS text) = upper(that)' LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE OPERATOR = (procedure=my_equals, leftarg=my_domain, rightarg = text);
```

The new operator is invoked causing a query containing lowercase letters to match the uppercase column value, but only if I cast the type of the `WHERE` clause:

```
sandbox=> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE val=CAST ('abc' AS text);
 val 
-----
 ABC
(1 row)

sandbox=> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE val='abc';
 val 
-----
(0 rows)
```

**Question**: What can I do so my custom equality operator is used without the cast?  In other words, how to cause the last query above return the table row (without changing the query)?  I have tried defining `my_equals()` so its second parameter type is either `varchar` and `char(3)`, but those still require a cast in the `WHERE`-clause of the query.  I've also tried `anyelement`, but that does not work even with a cast.